# Как правильно передавать сообщение об ошибке в нативном модуле HTTP NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Насколько я понял, есть несколько вариантов использования `response.end()` нативного модуля `http`.
Часто используют с едиными параметром - кодом ошибки (например, `response.end(404)`).
Видел и другой способ - указание статуса в заголовках:

```
rawResponse.statusCode = HTTP_StatusCodes.notFound;
rawResponse.end();
```

Воспрос такой: а как же передать на клиентскую часть сообщение об ошибке (например, "query-параметр foo должен быть строкой")?
Это нужно передавать именно в теле ответа как данные или ещё каким-то образом?

Comment: в [документации](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) всё написано. вот [так](https://pastebin.com/SnMgeRzs), например

Comment: кстати, в статье, которую я вам когда-то рекомендовал прочитать, об этом [написано](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module-ru#:~:text=res.end(JSON.stringify({error:%22Resource%20not%20found%22})))

Comment: @nörbörnën, Благодарю Вас за комментарий. То есть этот способ правильный... Понял! Кстати в документации не сказано про передачу кода HTTP-статуса первым параметром `response.end()`. Стало быть этот способ лучше не использовать?

Comment: `в документации не сказано про передачу кода HTTP-статуса первым параметром response.end()` -- а где про это сказано? вот вы задаёте вопрос `Стало быть этот способ лучше не использовать?`, но просто докажите _возможность использования_ такого подхода

Comment: @nörbörnën, скажу честно - я не помню, где это подсмотрел.  Главное что теперь узнал, как делать правильно. Доказать я Вам не смогу, потому что почти нет опыта в серверном программировании на Node.js.

Comment: я имел ввиду показать хоть какую-то ссылку в обоснование :)